# Python - BeautifulSoup wont scrape the rest of the li in the ul

Tags: python, html, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm looking to scrape information from an exam website that stores dates and exam files in English.
[Link provided here](https://www.geva.co.il/solution_term/english_2021_summer/)

For those who dont wish to inspect themselves, this is the relevant html:

```
<ul class="sub-terms">
<li class="single-sub-term">
<div class="single-sub-term-heading">
<h3>מועד א׳ - 26/05/2021</h3>
<p class="single-sub-term-description"></p></div>
    <ul class="pdf-list">
    <li class="pdf-item">
    <div class="pdf-info">
        <p><span class="first-line">16481</span></p>
```

**Problem: There are 3 li's in the ul 'sub-terms' - "single-sub-term" - where the exam name and date are stored. I need to access all 3 li's, but my code currently outputs on the first li and stops.**

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html_text = requests.get('https://www.geva.co.il/solution_term/english_2021_summer/').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')


entirePage = soup.find('ul', class_ = 'sub-terms')
lists = entirePage.find_all('li', class_ ='single-sub-term')
for list in lists:
    date = list.find('h3').text
    pdf_info = list.find('span', class_='first-line').text

    print(f'''Welcome! 
    Current date - {date}        Term Number : {pdf_info} ''')
    print('')
```

Output:

```
    Welcome! 
    Current date - מועד א׳ - 26/05/2021        Term Number : 16481 

Welcome! 
    Current date -  - 27/05/2021        Term Number : 16382 

Welcome! 
    Current date - מועד ב' - 05/07/2021        Term Number : 16381 - A
```

Comment: You want to extract all term numbers from associate li tags correct??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example will create pandas DataFrame from the page:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.geva.co.il/solution_term/english_2021_summer/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

all_data = []
for pdf_item in soup.select("li.pdf-item"):
    h3 = pdf_item.find_previous("h3").text
    number = pdf_item.select_one(".first-line").text
    for a in pdf_item.select("a.black-btn"):
        all_data.append(
            {
                "title": h3,
                "number": number,
                "link_text": a.text,
                "link": a["href"],
            }
        )

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                   title     number       link_text                                                                   link
0   מועד א׳ - 26/05/2021      16481    צפייה בשאלון       https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/E16481.pdf
1   מועד א׳ - 26/05/2021      16481  צפייה בפתרונות      https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/פתרון-E.pdf
2   מועד א׳ - 26/05/2021      16381    צפייה בשאלון     https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/A16381-2.pdf
3   מועד א׳ - 26/05/2021      16381  צפייה בפתרונות    https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/פתרון-A-1.pdf
4           - 27/05/2021      16382    צפייה בשאלון      https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16382-1.pdf
5           - 27/05/2021      16382  צפייה בפתרונות      https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/פתרון-C.pdf
6           - 27/05/2021      16384    צפייה בשאלון      https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16384-B.pdf
7           - 27/05/2021      16384  צפייה בפתרונות      https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/פתרון-B.pdf
8           - 27/05/2021      16484    צפייה בשאלון      https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16484-D.pdf
9           - 27/05/2021      16484  צפייה בפתרונות      https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/פתרון-D.pdf
10          - 27/05/2021      16582    צפייה בשאלון    https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16582-G-1.pdf
11          - 27/05/2021      16582  צפייה בפתרונות    https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/פתרון-G-1.pdf
12          - 27/05/2021      16584    צפייה בשאלון      https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16584-F.pdf
13          - 27/05/2021      16584  צפייה בפתרונות      https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/פתרון-F.pdf
14  מועד ב' - 05/07/2021  16381 - A    צפייה בשאלון        https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16381.pdf
15  מועד ב' - 05/07/2021  16381 - A  צפייה בפתרונות  https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16381-פתרון.pdf
16  מועד ב' - 05/07/2021  16384 - B    צפייה בשאלון        https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16384.pdf
17  מועד ב' - 05/07/2021  16384 - B  צפייה בפתרונות  https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16384-פתרון.pdf
18  מועד ב' - 05/07/2021  16382 - C    צפייה בשאלון    https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16382-1-1.pdf
19  מועד ב' - 05/07/2021  16382 - C  צפייה בפתרונות  https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16382-פתרון.pdf
20  מועד ב' - 05/07/2021  16484 - D    צפייה בשאלון        https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16484.pdf
21  מועד ב' - 05/07/2021  16484 - D  צפייה בפתרונות  https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16484-פתרון.pdf
22  מועד ב' - 05/07/2021  16481 - E    צפייה בשאלון        https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16481.pdf
23  מועד ב' - 05/07/2021  16481 - E  צפייה בפתרונות  https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16481-פתרון.pdf
24  מועד ב' - 05/07/2021  16584 - F    צפייה בשאלון        https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16584.pdf
25  מועד ב' - 05/07/2021  16584 - F  צפייה בפתרונות   https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16584פתרון.pdf
26  מועד ב' - 05/07/2021  16582 - G    צפייה בשאלון      https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16582-3.pdf
27  מועד ב' - 05/07/2021  16582 - G  צפייה בפתרונות  https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16582-פתרון.pdf
```

Comment: After I create this list, I look to create two further functionalities:
1. Download the pdfs associated with each test.
2. Export all extracted information to excel sheet

Is it achievable with pandas? or what further libraries would you recommend?

Comment: @ThomasReiner You can save dataframe to `.csv` or `.xls`, for example with `df.to_csv("data.csv", index=None)` command. For saving the PDFs you can use `requests` module as well.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    for x in soup.select('.single-sub-term-heading'):
        print(x.text)
        for i in x.next_sibling.select('.pdf-item'):
            print(i.select_one('span').text)
            print([a['href']
                  for a in i.select_one('.pdf-download').select('a')])


main('https://www.geva.co.il/solution_term/english_2021_summer/')
```

Output:

```
מועד א׳ - 26/05/2021
16481
['https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/E16481.pdf', 'https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/פתרון-E.pdf']
16381
['https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/A16381-2.pdf', 'https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/פתרון-A-1.pdf']
 - 27/05/2021
16382
['https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16382-1.pdf', 'https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/פתרון-C.pdf']
16384
['https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16384-B.pdf', 'https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/פתרון-B.pdf']
16484
['https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16484-D.pdf', 'https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/פתרון-D.pdf']
16582
['https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16582-G-1.pdf', 'https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/פתרון-G-1.pdf']
16584
['https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16584-F.pdf', 'https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/פתרון-F.pdf']
מועד ב' - 05/07/2021
16381 - A
['https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16381.pdf', 'https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16381-פתרון.pdf']
16384 - B
['https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16384.pdf', 'https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16384-פתרון.pdf']
16382 - C
['https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16382-1-1.pdf', 'https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16382-פתרון.pdf']
16484 - D
['https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16484.pdf', 'https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16484-פתרון.pdf']
16481 - E
['https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16481.pdf', 'https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16481-פתרון.pdf']
16584 - F
['https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16584.pdf', 'https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16584פתרון.pdf']
16582 - G
['https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16582-3.pdf', 'https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16582-פתרון.pdf']
(MyEnv) Lab> C:\Users\AmericaN\Desktop\Lab\MyEnv\Scripts\python.exe -u "c:\Users\AmericaN\Desktop\Lab\stack.py"
מועד א׳ - 26/05/2021
16481
['https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/E16481.pdf', 'https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/פתרון-E.pdf']    
16381
['https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/A16381-2.pdf', 'https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/פתרון-A-1.pdf']
 - 27/05/2021
16382
['https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16382-1.pdf', 'https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/פתרון-C.pdf']   
16384
['https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16384-B.pdf', 'https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/פתרון-B.pdf']   
16484
['https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16484-D.pdf', 'https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/פתרון-D.pdf']   
16582
['https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16582-G-1.pdf', 'https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/פתרון-G-1.pdf']
16584
['https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16584-F.pdf', 'https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/פתרון-F.pdf']
מועד ב' - 05/07/2021
16381 - A
['https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16381.pdf', 'https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16381-פתרון.pdf']
16384 - B
['https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16384.pdf', 'https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16384-פתרון.pdf']
16382 - C
['https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16382-1-1.pdf', 'https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16382-פתרון.pdf']
16484 - D
['https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16484.pdf', 'https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16484-פתרון.pdf']
16481 - E
['https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16481.pdf', 'https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16481-פתרון.pdf']
16584 - F
['https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16584.pdf', 'https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16584פתרון.pdf']
16582 - G
['https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16582-3.pdf', 'https://files.geva.co.il/geva_website/uploads/2021/05/16582-פתרון.pdf']
```